# Show sorted Json data based on property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have the following Data:

```
[
  {Genre: "Classical", Artist: "Vince", Site: "www.vinny.uk"}, 
  {Genre: "EDM", Artist: "Bart", Site: "www.barry.uk"}, 
  {Genre: "Rock", Artist: "Judas", Site: "www.judy.uk"}, 
  {Genre: "Rock", Artist: "Bran", Site: "www.branny.uk"}, 
  {Genre: "EDM", Artist: "Tom", Site: "www.tommy.uk"}
]
```

I want to show the data in a layout, which looks as followed:

```html
<div>
  <h1>Rock</h1>
  <a href="www.judy.uk"><h3>Judas</h3></a>
  <a href="www.branny.uk"><h3>Bran</h3></a>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>EDM</h1>
  <a href="www.barry.uk"><h3>Bart</h3></a>
  <a href="www.tommy.uk"><h3>Tom</h3></a>
</div>
<div>
  <h1>Classical</h1>
  <a href="www.vinny.uk"><h3>Vince</h3></a>
</div>
```

One important note is that I can't edit the Data.
I'm using JQuery btw.

Is it possible to loop the data so i dont have to type data[0].genre, data[1].genre etc for each genre?

How can I do that? Is it possible?
Maybe it's an easy or unclear question but I'm very new to this.

Comment: think about `for` loop

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8uamsfc2/

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieve this by using a for loop.
on [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) they explained it really well.
Also a ForEach could be really helpfull for this